# Movie where a girlfriend is abducted by a demon and loses her memory

Tags: story-identification, movie, demons

I'm trying to remember a movie I watched around 2013-2014.

In the beginning there is a young couple about to have sex in an old building (church?), and there is a very disturbing scene where she is stolen away by a demon/evil spirit creature. The man then searches for her.

Much later, he finds her in a huge house, but she no longer remembers him. There were other people living in the house. Maybe a wealthy man and a butler/servant? Not sure. I remember the movie being very trippy, but not necessarily a horror movie. I remember a scene with a swimming pool full of garbage.

Trying to remember the title has really been bothering me!

Comment: [_Lo_ (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lo_(film)) involves a girlfriend who was abducted by a demon, but doesn't include most of the other things you described, so I'm guessing it's probably not the movie you're looking for.